# Mi tabla llenada con javascript no carga datatable

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, api, fetch

Tengo un problema con el DataTable de jQuery, no se muestran las opciones al momento de implementarlo, estoy consumiendo una API REST que hice con Node js pero no me funciona y arroja este error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')", mi tabla en HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-dark table-striped shadow">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nombres</th>
                            <th>Primer apellido</th>
                            <th>Segundo apellido</th>
                            <th>Cédula</th>
                            <th>Sexo</th>
                            <th>Dirección</th>
                            <th>Télefono</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="tbodyP">
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Este es el script que uso para llenar la tabla HTML (el método constante mostrar), url es la ruta de conexion con la api rest de node js y contenedor el tbody de la tabla:

```
const url = "http://xxxxxx/x/personas";
const contenedor = document.querySelector('.tbodyP');
const tablaPer = document.querySelector('.example');


const mostrar = (personas) => {

    personas.forEach(persona => {

        resultados += `
        <tr>
                <td>${persona.idPersona}</td>
                <td>${persona.nombrePersona}</td>
                <td>${persona.aPaterno}</td>
                <td>${persona.aMaterno}</td>
                <td>${persona.cedula}</td>
                <td>${persona.sexo}</td>
                <td>${persona.direccion}</td>
                <td>${persona.telefono}</td>
                <td>${persona.correoElectronico}</td>
                <td><a class="btnEditar btn btn-primary text-tencer">Edit</a><a class="btnBorrar btn btn-danger text-tencer">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        `

    });

    contenedor.innerHTML = resultados;
}


fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => mostrar(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Estos scripts debía agregarlos y ya están todos al final de la página, antes del cierre del body.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

Y estos son los links que debía agregar para que funcionen los estilos del datatable, en concreto es el de bootstrap 5, también estoy utizando ese framework.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
```

Este es el script que me apareció en la página oficial, el que debo usar para que funcione todo, está después de todos los otros scripts.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: No se si usas datatable o no, pues no veo su creación, pero si lo estás usando, creo que la fila `<tr></tr>` que dejas vacia en tu HTML quizas le esté molestado al hacer el .draw

Comment: Sí tengo los datatable, tengo todos los CDNs que pide para un tema en concreto, voy a editar la pregunta agregandolos... aunque pude solucionar una parte del problema ahora las opciones del datatable cargan pero no hace paginación y tampoco sirven las demás opciones....

Comment: por que estas cargando tu los  datos, los datos se los tienes que pasar en la definición del data table para que los cargue

Comment: cómo sería? estoy usando JavaScript puro...

Comment: Aqui tienes un ejemplo: https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects

Comment: haber según lo que entiendo  estas usando fecht para traer tus datos y luego estas ejecutando la función mostrar para que cargue los datos en tu tabla, lo que tendrías que hacer es en lugar de usar fecht es usar ajax del datatable para traer los datos y así se puedan cargar de manera correcta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haber creo que tendría que quedarte algo asíi

```
 <script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
     const url = "http://xxxxxx/x/personas";
        $("#example").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": url,
    "type": "POST",
    "datatype": "json"
    },
    "data": null,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "idPersona" },
        { "data": "nombrePersona" },
        { "data": "aPaterno" },
        { "data": "aMaterno" },
        { "data": "cedula" },
        { "data": "sexo" },
        { "data": "direccion" },
        { "data": "telefono" },
        { "data": "correoElectronico" },
        {
          "data": null, "sortable": false, "autoWidth": true, "render": function(data, type, full) {
          return `<a class="btnEditar btn btn-primary text-tencer" href = "#">Editar</a>
          <a class= "btnBorrar btn btn-danger text-tencer" href = "#">Eliminar</a>`;
          }
        },
        
    ],
    
     });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: a esto le puedes agregar y modificar muchas cosas tales como la cantidad de datos que quieres que muestre, la posición de los elementos, la ordenación de los datos, etc.  Además que puedes exportar los datos a excel, pdf o imprimirlos directamente, date una pasada por la documentación de Data Table y veras las maravillas que se pueden hacer

Comment: Hola, disculpa la ignorancia, estoy aprendiendo de JQuery y DataTables pero ¿dónde debo colocar ese código?

Comment: tienes que eliminar toda la parte donde llenas tu tabla y poner este código dentro del  $(document).ready(function () {
            "aquí va el código"  
        });

Comment: con la edición que hice solo tendrías que remplazar lo que tienes en js por mi respuesta

Comment: Gracias, lo había adaptado ya pero igual la ayuda no está de más, muchas gracias, ahora el problema que tengo es que me muestra dos veces las filas.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha ya eliminaste tu código donde cargas tu la tabla  con el forech

Comment: Sí, me sale: jquery-3.5.1.js:4055 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style');

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Vas a tener que abrir otra pregunta para que empecemos desde ahí o editar esta pregunta con detalles de tu error